# How to exclude previous captured group

Tags: java, regex

Here is my requirement, I want to recognize a valid String definition in compiler design, the string should either start and end with double quote (`"hello world"`), or start and end with single quote(`'hello world'`).

I used `(['"]).*\1` to achieve the goal, the `\1` here is to reference previous first captured group, namely first single or double quote, as explanation from [regex 101](https://regex101.com/),

```
\1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
```

It works so far so good.
Then I got new requirement, which is to treat an inner single quote in external single quotes as invalid vase, and same to double quotes situation. Which means both `'hello ' world'` and `"hello " world"` are invalid case.

I think the solution should not be hard if we can represent **not** previous 1st captured group, something like `(['"])(?:NOT\1)*\1`.

The `(?:)` here is used as a non capturing group, to make sure `\1` represents to first quote always. But the key is how to replace NOT with correct regex symbol. It's not like my previous experience about exclusion, like `[^abcd]` to exclude `abcd`, but to exclude the previous capture group and the symbol `^` doesn't work that way.

Comment: I would actually try something like this: https://regex101.com/r/2VrGqZ/1 (and match it against the entire input)

Comment: @LorenzHetterich Thanks for the sharing, yes, it's absolutely can be a workable solution. But I just curious if there is what I called NOT previous 1st capture. Let's leave the thread here to see if others can contribute on this part.

Comment: Is this for validation from start to end? It sounds like you wanted e.g. [`^(['"])(?:(?!\1).)*\1$`](https://regex101.com/r/YRqBvb/1) ([explanation at RexEgg](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)). But *alternating* between the options and using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) inside would be much more efficient: [`^(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')$`](https://regex101.com/r/mr4W7m/1) (watch steps counter)

Comment: @Eugene yes, what you are looking for actually (kind of) exists. The "negative lookahead" `?!`, example here: https://regex101.com/r/5nUDze/1 . However, it is quite weird since it does not match any characters (just stops the match, if the pattern does not match). So it basically is treated as zero-length (thus, the `.` right after)

Comment: Last but probably not least you could further capture and check if there are not two more of the same type ahead: [`^(['"])(?!(?:.*?\1){2}).*`](https://regex101.com/r/NKIMNE/1) but I would go with [@LorenzHetterich's first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74541660/how-to-exclude-previous-captured-group#comment131582862_74541660) :)

Comment: Thanks for both of you's further explanation. Please summarize them to an answer if you want and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **most efficient** method for this is probably a simple *alternation*, like already mentioned by [@LorenzHetterich in his first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74541660/how-to-exclude-previous-captured-group#comment131582862_74541660). Easy to read, a short pattern and it gets the job done.

```
^(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mr4W7m/1)

This just [alternates](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) between either pairs of quotes [without](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) [any](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of the same quote-type inside.

---

The technique to *exclude a capture* between certain parts, that you were outlining is known as [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed). Best to use it if there are no other options available (*not* for this task).

```
^(['"])(?:(?!\1).)*\1$
```

[Another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YRqBvb/1)

The *greedy* dot gets *tempered* by [what was captured](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) in the *first group* and won't skip over.

Similar to this solution but much *more efficient*:
• [Unrolled star alternation solution](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#unrolled_staralt): [`^(['"])[^"']*+(?:(?!\1)['"][^"']*)*\1$`](https://regex101.com/r/YRqBvb/2) (efficient)
• [Explicit greedy alternation solution](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#explicit_greed): [`^(['"])(?:[^"']++|(?!\1)["'])*\1$`](https://regex101.com/r/YRqBvb/3) (a bit slower)
Especially for the latter use of a [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) is crucial to [avoid runaway issues](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

---

Just for having it mentioned, another option is using a negative *lookahead* to check after capturing the first match if there are *not* two more ahead. Also not highly efficient but sometimes useful.

```
^(['"])(?!(?:.*?\1){2}).*
```

[One more demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NKIMNE/1)

---

*FYI:* If the pattern is used with Java [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()), the `^` *start* and `$` *end* [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) are not needed.